# BitLocker Drive Decrypt Methods

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, bitlocker, decrypt

I have a hard disk 1,5 TB with 2 partitions 1 TB and 0,5 TB.
The one partition 1 TB was encrypted with Windows 7 BitLocker.
One day the encrypted BitLocker partition failed to boot and seems like damaged so I deleted the two partitions and I made quick format, then I locate the hole space without format, so now  my disk it seems like RAW SPACE (RANDOM)!

The question is, **can I decrypt the partition with the password that I used to logon** into BitLocker or I need the recovery key because I didn't keep it.

If not an other question will be, **can I regenerate my recovery key from password that I used to logon** into BitLocker?

Comment: Even if you could decrypt the partition the data is already gone because you performed a quick format on it.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is, can i decrypt the partition with the password that i used to logon into bitlocker or i need the recovery key because i didn't keep it.

No. The password decrypts the key, but you don't have an encrypted key.

> If not an other question will be, can i regenerate my recovery key from password that i used to logon into bitlocker?

No. The recovery key is randomly-generated. Recovering it requires a backup of the key.

By intentional design, there are only two precise ways to access the encryption key. If you can't meet the requirements for either of those, you cannot decrypt the data.